# How to stop fake reviews and fake signups on Magento 1 and Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-1, extensions, security

We have 2 websites one is on Magento 1 and the second is on Magento 2 , In both websites we get fake reviews and fake signups everyday. Someone told me to add captcha which will not let bots or automated softwares to make fake reviews and fake signups. Any other solutions? or captcha is the best solution ?

If there are some extensions or any other solutions please give detail answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3beta.html) can help. Its not perfect, but when I implemented it on a contact form, it had a noticeable impact on the amount of spam coming in.

If you don't already have your site on a service like [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), you should do that. The free tier will give your some performance improvements and will filter a lot of bad traffic. With the paid plans you can start to create custom rules that can help you filter out some of the junk that comes in.

Its not fool-proof, I still get spam on my site, but its a start.

You can also make sure that you require e-mail confirmation for new accounts, and don't allow guest reviews. You'll still get spam, but at least they won't have as large of an impact on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps.

1. Enable captcha for customers signup which is the default functionality of Magento2.

   **Login to adminend** -> **Stores** -> **Configuration** -> Customers ->**Customer Configuration** -> **CAPTCHA**

[image]

2. Allow reviews only by registered customers which are an admin end-setting for Magento2

**Login to adminend** -> **Stores** -> **Configuration** -> **Catalog** ->**Catalog** -> **Product Reviews** -> **Allow Guests to Write Reviews**

[image]